# Disable change tracking in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, change-tracking

I have a Automation account AA1 with Log Analytics workspaces LA1 connected. I have used LA1 for [Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking), Now that i have on boarded all Azure VMs from 2 subscriptions it was time to on board Non Azure VMs which was an on premise VM(And i did manage to do it) but while enabling Change tracking i selected *Enable on all available and future machines* 
[image]

instead of *Enable on selected machines* now manage machines option is grayed out and i can't change this. How to disable or revert back the changes.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-add-solutions#remove-a-management-solution but this is asking to delete solution itself(not sure what this does).

Instead i went to the solution>Workspace Data Sources>VMs> selected a VM> Disconnect(Thinking this right way) but the disconnecting is still happening.

A proper step by step guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should delete the solution first, then you can re-configure it again.

Follow this doc [List installed monitoring solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solutions#list-installed-monitoring-solutions), find the related solutions -> then delete all the related solution. The screenshot as below:

[image]

Note: if you also enable it in the "Update Management" in azure automation, you should also delete the solution like `Updates(log_analytics_name)`.

After that, you can re-configure "Change tracking".

Comment: What all will be lost if i go ahead with deleting the solution and yes Update management is enabled.